# GetWindowDC(NULL) failing

Tags: winapi, qt4, gdi

I've a function that calls `GetWindowDC(NULL)`. and that function is called by different threads. sometimes I see `GetWindowDC(NULL)` returning `0x0` Why ? and How to resolve ? the function is mutex gaurded properly. So thats not a Problem. Do I need to `sleep()` few ms after each call ? and Why ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

### msdn Says

> **Return Value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to a device context for the specified window.
>   If the function fails, the return value is NULL, **indicating an error** or an invalid hWnd parameter.

but What this **indicating an error** means I couldn't understand

### Edit:

and Ya I am releasing all the DCs and also Deleting the DCs properly
Giving an immediate call to `GetLastError` retrns `0`
tried.

```
if(hdc == 0x0)
    qDebug() << GetLastError()
```

Here goes my source code. It **Works** but after working more than a 100 times (35-40 secs) it refuses to work and `GetWindowDC(NULL)` returns `0`

```
QPixmap Util::grabScreen(const DG::Rect* rect){
    mutex.lock();

    HDC hdc=GetWindowDC(NULL);
    HWND win=WindowFromDC(hdc);

    HDC cdc=CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP temp=CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc,rect->width,rect->height);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    hdc=BeginPaint(win,&ps);
    HBITMAP oldb=(HBITMAP)SelectObject(cdc,temp);
    BitBlt(cdc,0,0,rect->width,rect->height,hdc,rect->top,rect->left,SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(cdc,oldb);
    EndPaint(win,&ps);

    char* buff;
    buff = new char[rect->size()];
    GetBitmapBits(temp,rect->size(),buff);
    qDebug() << "temp" << temp;
    if(temp == 0x0){
        qDebug() << "hdc" << hdc;
    }

    DeleteDC(cdc);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
    DeleteDC(hdc);

    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromWinHBITMAP(temp);
    //QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWidget(desktopWidget,rect->toQRect());
    mutex.unlock();
    return pixmap;

}
```

Comment: There is a limited number of DC's, how often do you call GetWindowDC exactly? ...and are you releasing it back to the system?

Comment: Ya I am releasing and deleting the DCs at the end. and this function is simultaneously called by 16 threads. I'vent counted the how often. But its seems its very very often. So exactly how long Should I `sleep()` ?

Comment: Call `GetLastError()` immediately after the function fails should give you more information about what happened.

Comment: @Dave Rager: I just gave that a Try. `if(hdc == 0x0)qDebug() << GetLastError()` It returns `0`. So what Might be causing it ?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you shouldn't call `DeleteDC` on an handle obtained using `GetDC`. You should just call `ReleaseDC` instead.

Comment: I've tried by removing the `DeleteDC` but still the problem persists

Answer (score -1):

Without know more details on what is going on; the scenario sounds a bit odd to me.
However...

Is it possible that code is also processing a WM_PAINT for the same window at the same time you are trying to get the WindowDC ?

I'm not sure if you can obtain a window DC for the same window that is being actively painted.

Comment: This is `GetWindowDC(NULL)` on the Desktop Window I am not performing any painting from my application.